# How to Build a Table that Summarizes Multiple Values at Once in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, dplyr

I have a dataframe (titled df1) with multiple columns that contain Yes, No or NA answers.

```
     A    B   C    D
1  Yes   No  No  Yes
2  Yes   No  No   No
3 <NA>  Yes Yes <NA>
4   No <NA>  No  Yes
```

My goal is to create a table that counts the frequency of each answer and output a table with the original column name as follows:

```
  Answer A B C D
1    Yes 2 1 1 2
2     No 1 2 3 1
3   <NA> 1 1 0 1
```

My approach so far has been to build a function then loop over that function, but the output doesn't product a table with all of the categories (A through D).

```
my_function <- function(table_name,col_name) {
  table_name %>% 
    group_by_(Answer = col_name) %>%
    summarise(!!paste0(col_name):= n())}

my_categories <- c("A","B","C","D")

for(i in 1:length(my_categories)){
  df2 <- myfunction(df1,CSAT_Cols[i])
}
```

I'm also open to different approaches if there's an easier method, but TL:DR, trying to loop over grouping by multiple categories, summarizing by n(), then creating single table with all of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then back to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` while specifying the `values_fn` as `length` on the different column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_to = 'Answer') %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = name, 
       values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

-ouput

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Answer     A     B     C     D
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Yes        2     1     1     2
2 No         1     2     3     1
3 <NA>       1     1     0     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("Yes", "Yes", NA, "No"), B = c("No", "No", 
"Yes", NA), C = c("No", "No", "Yes", "No"), D = c("Yes", "No", 
NA, "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a base R option using `table` can help you

```
> table(unlist(df), names(df)[col(df)], useNA = "ifany")

       A B C D
  No   1 2 3 1
  Yes  2 1 1 2
  <NA> 1 1 0 1
```